# How do I have text scroll and fade in when a page loads?

Tags: html, css, text, fade

I am looking for how the text could load on the page and appear to show one letter at a time from left to right fading in on the page. However, when the text loads, I would like it so the a letter slightly increases and decreases in size once. So, the letter appear like a Mexican wave when loading.

I have managed the below code, which is a bit too much of a typewriter feel and cuts off part of a letter. I wonder if anyone would know a solution?

Many thanks,

```
.line-1{ 
width: 100%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center; 
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden; 
} 

.anim-typewriter{ 
text-align: center; 
animation: typewriter 2s 0.5s 1 normal both; 
} 
@keyframes typewriter{ 
from{width: 0;} 
to{width: 100%;} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a visual example?

Comment: Sure, if you skip a few seconds into the video, but the white text in the black speech bubbles at the top of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgBRLRaEdws

Answer (score 0):

I found some examples if you want to use only html and css (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/)

If you want to animate the letters one by one you will have to use javascript though.

You could try making a timed function that each 0.5 secs creates a new element containing just one letter, add a class that animates the letter by making it bigger and smaller and merge the letter element with the text.

Or maybe you could make the css animation for the single letter and then just create a new element with that class every 0.5 seconds.

Examples (i'm using dummy tags):

1st option would look like: `<text> first part of the te </text> <letter class="mexican"> x </letter>`

2nd option would look like: `<letter class="mexican"> f </letter><letter class="mexican"> i </letter><letter class="mexican"> r </letter><letter class="mexican"> s </letter>`

Comment: Perfect thank you, I will look into this and test it out. Thank you.